# Scalatest html reports

Tags: html, unit-testing, scala, reporting, scalatest

I'm trying to get an html report of the scalatest and I've found a lot of configurations like this:

```
<plugin>                                                                                
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>                                                    
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>                                     
    <version>1.0-M2</version>                                                           
    <configuration>                                                                     
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>                                     
        <filereports>NCXEHLOWFD file/constrained.txt,file/full.txt</filereports>        
        <xmlreports>xml</xmlreports>                                                    
        <htmlreports>html/report.html</htmlreports>                                     
    </configuration>                                                                    
    <executions>                                                                        
        <execution>                                                                     
            <id>test</id>                                                               
            <goals>                                                                     
                <goal>test</goal>                                                       
            </goals>                                                                    
        </execution>                                                                    
    </executions>                                                                       
</plugin>
```

But IntelliJ tells me that `xmlreports` and `htmlreports` are not allowed, and no xml or html reports are generated.

Can anyone suggest anything?
I'll be very thankful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the latest plugin version currently available `1.0-M4-SNAP1` instead of `1.0-M2` which doesn't have `htmlreports` property. Here are important part from my pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.9.3</scala.version>
        <scalatest.version>2.0.M5b</scalatest.version>
        <scalatest.plugin.version>1.0-M4-SNAP1</scalatest.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${scalatest.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                    <htmlreporters>${project.build.directory}/html/scalatest</htmlreporters>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- required by scalatest-maven-plugin to generate HTML report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pegdown</groupId>
            <artifactId>pegdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

With this setting I can run `mvn clean install` and it will produce nice HTML report under `${project.build.directory}/html/scalatest`

Comment: You may have to add another dependency: com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.35.10

Answer (score 2):

[image]

@rozky's solution works for me but the css is awkward. It doesn't display the table correctly. It doesn't show me the suite name column in the table no matter what version of pegdown and scalatest-maven-plugin I use :/